# Array Question. Any ideas on how to solve my problem?

Tags: c#

I have around 1000 array elements. The elements consist of 1 user ID per element.

What I would like to do is shorten this array so each element contains 10 user ID's per element and each user ID per element is delimited by a comma.

Current array:

```
324234
2342234
0983242
....
```

New Array:

```
324234,2342342,234234234,234234,5436436,457456,456456,234234,234234,546456436
34234,23423426,54645654,34532423,23423432,4634634,2342342,234234,264353,345345
....
```

You may be asking WHY DO THAT?!

Well, I am sending the ID's to a post request. The request accepts either 1 ID or more. To shorten the number of requests I would like to send along 10 ID's per request.

Any ideas on how to group the old array into the new shorter array?

Answer (score 2):

Then why don't you send them all once as a CSV ?

**Later edit:**

Note: code not tested

```
int amountPerCall = 10;
List<string> ids = new ArrayList<string>();
// add ids...
for (int i = 0 ; i < ids.Count; i += amountPerCall) {
    Send(String.Join(",", ids, i, amountPerCall));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to send them all because the service I am posting to can be unpredictable. I'd be safe at 10, but sending the whole 1000 could result in an error on the servers end.

Comment: The API might have an upper limit of 10 IDs per request.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq)'s [`Batch`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) method:

```
IEnumerable<string> batches = input.Batch(10, ids => string.Join(",", ids));
```

If you don't want to use MoreLINQ itself, you can just look at the code to get an idea for what it does.

(Depending on which version of .NET you're using, you may need to convert the input to `string.Join` into an array. .NET 4 has introduced some helpful new overloads to that method.)